# Game Graphics - Quality Dependent FPS Control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, performance, graphics

I'm currently making a game (in vb.net) that uses the [Graphics class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) to draw most of the game objects, but i've run into the old problem of performance. To combat the lagging i've added some code to automatically lower the game quality so i can try to boost the game's speed, this works to a degree, but even still the game slows down quite noticeable when more "enemies" are added to the higher levels. I quite new to the graphics class (only started to use it a few days ago), so the only things i know that help speed up my game are: turning off Anti Aliasing, and lowering the Timer interval (which pretty much governs my games refresh rate), so besides the previous, are there any other ways to improve my game's performance?

Game screenshot...
[image: Screenshot]

Here's my code so far (the quality adjustment bit is at the bottom),

```
Public Class Form1

Private keysPressed As New HashSet(Of Keys)
Private firstRun As Boolean = True
Private mouseDownB As Boolean = False
Private newLevel As Boolean = True
Private randomColour As New Random
Private RandomEnemyX As New Random
Private RandomEnemyY As New Random
Private RandomEnemySide As New Random
Private life As Integer = 5
Private score As String = 0
Private playerX As Integer = 403
Private playerY As Integer = 206
Private totaltEnemyCount As Integer = 10
Private enemyCount As Integer = 0
Private enemyX(0) As Integer
Private enemyY(0) As Integer
Private enemyID(0) As Integer
Private EX As Integer = 0
Private EY As Integer = 0
Private ES As Integer = 0
Private enemyMoved As Integer
Private enemySpeed As Integer = 1
Private enemyAttacked As Integer = 0
Private enemyActive As Integer = 0
Private levelNumber As Long = 0
Private FPS As Integer = 40
Private g1 As Graphics
Private enemyCountIncrease As Boolean = True
Private enemySpeedIncrease As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    g1 = Me.CreateGraphics
    g1.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias                           
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    mouseDownB = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    mouseDownB = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        keysPressed.Add(Keys.Left)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        keysPressed.Add(Keys.Up)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        keysPressed.Add(Keys.Right)
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        keysPressed.Add(Keys.Down)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    keysPressed.Remove(e.KeyCode)
End Sub
'''''''''''''''''''''''''Random colour generator''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Function R() As String
    Return randomColour.Next(0, 255)
End Function

Private Function G() As String
    Return randomColour.Next(0, 255)
End Function

Private Function B() As String
    Return randomColour.Next(0, 255)
End Function
'''''''''''''''''''''''''Random location generator''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Function X() As String
    Return RandomEnemyX.Next(0, 494)
End Function

Private Function Y() As String
    Return RandomEnemyY.Next(24, 348)
End Function
'''''''''''''''''''''''''Main display & player generation''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Sub mainPaint(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Interval = FPS
    Dim ST As New Stopwatch
    ST.Start()
    If firstRun = True Then
        levelNumber = levelNumber + 1
        g1.DrawString("Level " & levelNumber, New Font("DigifaceWide", 64, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(191, R, G, B)), X, Y)
        g1.DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.FromArgb(128, R, G, B)), 0, 0, 884, 24)
        g1.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, R, G, B)), playerX, playerY, 24, 24)
        g1.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, R, G, B)), 0, 0, 884, 24)
        g1.DrawString("Life: 5", New Font("DigifaceWide", 20, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(191, R, G, B)), 2, 0)
        g1.DrawString("Score: 0", New Font("DigifaceWide", 20, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(191, R, G, B)), 100, 0)
        firstRun = False
    End If
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Move player''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If keysPressed.Contains(Keys.Left) Then
        If playerX > 0 Then
            playerX = playerX - 5
            g1.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, R, G, B)), playerX, playerY, 24, 24)
        End If
    ElseIf keysPressed.Contains(Keys.Up) Then
        If playerY > 24 Then
            playerY = playerY - 5
            g1.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, R, G, B)), playerX, playerY, 24, 24)
        End If
    ElseIf keysPressed.Contains(Keys.Right) Then
        If playerX < 860 Then
            playerX = playerX + 5
            g1.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, R, G, B)), playerX, playerY, 24, 24)
        End If
    ElseIf keysPressed.Contains(Keys.Down) Then
        If playerY < 388 Then
            playerY = playerY + 5
            g1.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, R, G, B)), playerX, playerY, 24, 24)
        End If
    End If
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Laser generation'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If mouseDownB = True Then
        g1.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.FromArgb(102, R, G, B)), playerX + 12, playerY + 12, Control.MousePosition.X - Me.Bounds.X, Control.MousePosition.Y - Me.Bounds.Y)
    End If
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Enemy generation - New level''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If newLevel = True Then
        levelNumber = levelNumber + 1
        Do While enemyCount < totaltEnemyCount
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            ReDim enemyID(0)
            Do While enemyID.Length <= totaltEnemyCount
                EX = RandomEnemyX.Next(0, 872)
                EY = RandomEnemyY.Next(24, 400)
                ES = RandomEnemySide.Next(0, 4)
                ReDim Preserve enemyID(i + 1)
                enemyID(i) = 1
                ReDim Preserve enemyX(i + 1)
                ReDim Preserve enemyY(i + 1)
                If ES = 0 Then 'Left side
                    enemyX(i) = 0
                    enemyY(i) = EY
                ElseIf ES = 1 Then 'Top side
                    enemyX(i) = EX
                    enemyY(i) = 24
                ElseIf ES = 2 Then 'Right side
                    enemyX(i) = 872
                    enemyY(i) = EY
                ElseIf ES = 3 Then 'Bottom side
                    enemyX(i) = EX
                    enemyY(i) = 400
                End If
                g1.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Red)), enemyX(i), enemyY(i), 12, 12)
                enemyCount = enemyID.Length
                enemyActive = enemyActive + 1
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        Loop
        newLevel = False
    End If
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Enemy attacked''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim iii As Integer = 0
    Do While iii < totaltEnemyCount
        If (((Control.MousePosition.X - Me.Location.X) > enemyX(iii))) And ((Control.MousePosition.X - Me.Location.X) < (enemyX(iii) + 16)) And ((Control.MousePosition.Y - Me.Location.Y) > enemyY(iii)) And ((Control.MousePosition.Y - Me.Location.Y) < (enemyY(iii) + 16)) Then
            If mouseDownB = True Then
                enemyID(iii) = -1
                enemyX(iii) = -1
                enemyY(iii) = -1
                enemyActive = enemyActive - 1
                enemyCount = enemyCount - 1
            End If
        End If
        iii = iii + 1
    Loop
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Move enemy'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim ii As Integer = 0
    Do While enemyMoved < totaltEnemyCount
        If enemyActive < 1 Then
            enemyCount = 0
            newLevel = True
            If enemyCountIncrease = True Then
                totaltEnemyCount = totaltEnemyCount + 50
            ElseIf enemySpeedIncrease = True Then
                enemySpeed = enemySpeed + 1
            End If
            g1.DrawString("Level " & levelNumber, New Font("DigifaceWide", 64, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(191, R, G, B)), X, Y)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If enemyID(ii) = -1 Then
            GoTo skipMove
        End If
        If (enemyX(ii) - (playerX + 4)) < 0 Then 'Enemy on left
            enemyX(ii) = enemyX(ii) + enemySpeed
        End If
        If (enemyX(ii) - (playerX + 4)) > 0 Then 'Enemy on right
            enemyX(ii) = enemyX(ii) - enemySpeed
        End If
        If (enemyY(ii) - (playerY + 4)) < 0 Then 'Enemy above
            enemyY(ii) = enemyY(ii) + enemySpeed
        End If
        If (enemyY(ii) - (playerY + 4)) > 0 Then 'Enemy below
            enemyY(ii) = enemyY(ii) - enemySpeed
        End If
        g1.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(51, Color.Red)), enemyX(ii), enemyY(ii), 12, 12)
skipMove:
        enemyMoved = enemyMoved + 1
        ii = ii + 1
    Loop
    enemyMoved = 0
    ''''''''''''''''''''''QDSA - Quality Depentant Speed Adjustment''''''''''''''''''''
    ST.Stop()
        Dim elapTick As Decimal = ST.ElapsedTicks
        If elapTick < 5000 Then 'Slow down
            FPS = FPS + 1
            enemySpeedIncrease = False
            g1.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
            enemyCountIncrease = True
        ElseIf elapTick > 5000 Then 'Speed up
            If FPS > 1 Then
                FPS = FPS - 1
            End If
            g1.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None
            enemyCountIncrease = False
            If enemySpeed < 4 Then
                enemySpeedIncrease = True
            Else
                enemySpeedIncrease = False
            End If
        End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Dude, winforms a really old UI technology and is not intended for these kind of things. Have you considered using WPF? it's much more scalable and performant. It's also hardware-accelerated and doesn't have the flicker / slowness issues winforms has. Also, there's a signficant amount of code you could reduce using WPF, and leveraging the `DataTemplate` and `Animation` capabilities.

Comment: If you wish, post a screenshot of what you have and I can give you an idea how to implement it in WPF.

Comment: Right ok, i've never used WPF before, i'll give it a try though, thanks. I'll also add the screenshot...

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit? I don't see anything but mixed colors, what's the idea of the game?

Comment: The top bar is where the player's score, life, etc, is displayed. The main object of the game, is too move your circle (the multi-colored circle) around the screen and fire your laser (the thin multi-colored lines) at the red circles, the red circles follow the player and if the player touches any of the red circles then the player will lose a life.

Comment: can you post a not-so-bloated screenshot? with less objects so I can see what's the idea... I think that the problem might be you're not erasing the previous positions when you move?

Comment: Sure. Yeah i can't seem to erase the previous move of the animation without causing  serious flickering.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28215/discussion-between-highcore-and-sam)

Comment: If you are making games you might also want to consider MonoGame (open source port of XNA that supports many platforms).

Comment: Part of the problem is that your mainPaint method is trying to do too much.  Its sole responsibility should be in displaying your objects (player, enemies, etc.) in their current state.  But you've got it moving your enemies, and doing other things that should not be in the paint event.  Basically you should have a main game loop with separate methods for getting user input, updating the state of your objects and then painting the objects.

Comment: So if i were to move everything that has nothing to do with actually painting the game objects to separate Subs/Functions then it might help improve performance?

Comment: Well, it couldn't hurt, and I think it would make your program easier to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made a sample WPF project similar to what you need, just to give you an idea how powerful and beautiful and fast WPF is compared to ancient technologies.

It looks like this:

[image]

It's a little too much code to post it here entirely, so [here is a link](https://anonfiles.com/file/9cae0f3766ed95a78d48b4e8cdf345c9) to a RAR file with the full source.

The main UI XAML is this:

```
<Window x:Class="SamsGameSample.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SamsGameSample"
        Title="SamsGameSample"
        PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown"
        PreviewKeyUp="Window_PreviewKeyUp"
        SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Player}">
            <Ellipse Fill="Green" Stroke="Black" Height="{Binding Size.Height}" Width="{Binding Size.Width}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Enemy}">
            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" Height="{Binding Size.Height}" Width="{Binding Size.Width}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0" Opacity=".6">
                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset=".5"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </DockPanel.Background>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#70000000" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lives, StringFormat='Lives: {0}'}" Margin="10" Foreground="AliceBlue"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score, StringFormat='Score: {0}'}" Margin="10" Foreground="AliceBlue"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GameObjects}" x:Name="GameArea">
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Location.X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Location.Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

- Compare the amount of code in my project (and the cleanliness of it) to the multiple hacks you need to do almost anything in winforms.
- Also compare the performance, and the resolution independence.