# Binding Ellipse to an object

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I need to write a program in which several circles are moving around a bigger circle. I create them using ellipse and canvas. The thing is, I have a library which is responsible for moving the objects around the circle. It has a list of so called Runners which have the following properties: `CurrentAngle` and `CurrentPosition`. How can I bind an ellipse to these Runner objects? I also have trouble figuring out this `ItemsControl`. Without it at least the circles were drawn. Now the screen is empty. My code so far is:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="10" Height="10" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Height="10" Width="10">
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform CenterX="150" CenterY="150" Angle="{Binding Path=CurrentAngle}" />
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            </Ellipse>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I set the `DataContext` to the list of Runner objects.

Comment: See my example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16019877/643085)

Comment: Your ItemsPanelTemplate size is only 10x10, are you sure you want it that small, you will only be able to fit 1 ellipse