# C# - Draw text outside, and above, picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, text, draw

I am currently making a little game where the player is a PictureBox, that can move around. And I am struggling with adding a name-tag above the player (PictureBox). I can't seem to set the X and Y position of the text to be outside the box. It just lands inside. I made a picture showing and describing what I want to achieve:

[image]

Here is my code to draw the character name. By the way, my character name is stored in the variable **CharacterName.charName**

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Draw character name upon start
        ListToPaint.Add(new WhatToPaint { X = 10, Y = 10, Text = CharacterName.charName });
    }

    private List<WhatToPaint> ListToPaint = new List<WhatToPaint>();
    private class WhatToPaint
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    private void player_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //This is the "Paint" properties on my PictureBox, called Player
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        foreach (WhatToPaint wp in ListToPaint)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(wp.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, wp.X, wp.Y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: winforms is not an adequate technology for games, nor anything else I can think of. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16019877/643085).

Comment: It's hard to tell just from the code you provided, but you'll have to put the text in the same container as the pictureBox (not _within_ the pictureBox).  Then you could just use coordinate math to put it (y) pixels above the pictureBox.

Comment: @ryanyuyu when you say container, you mean I should for example put a transparent panel behind the picture box? And then move the whole panel. And on that panel is like a text label and the PictureBox?

Comment: @aliazik Something like that.  That way the Label and PictureBox would have the same coordinate reference (since they are in the same container).

Comment: @ryanyuyu Nice! But I still don't see any option to center the label text. When I put a short name like "John" it looks fine and is centered. But when I put a name like "Big John From London" it kind of goes off on the right side. And there's no option in the properties to set the label text as centered

Comment: @aliazik I don't know off the top of my head, but there's probably another question here that deals with that.  If not, you'll have to do something like using the width of the text box to find where the midpoint would be.  Then offset by that midpoint (yet more coordinate math).

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thanks! I sorted it! Woohoo! :)

Comment: @aliazik Glad to hear it.  For completion's sake I'm going to post a [community-wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) containing the information in the comments.  You will be able to vote and/or accept it.  Since it's a community wiki you can even edit it with any other information.  I'm only going to include the overall ideas, so you could for example include actual working code.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the Label in the same container as the PictureBox (not within the pictureBox), you could just use coordinate math to put it (y) pixels above the PictureBox

For example you could put the Label and Picture box into a transparent Panel.  You could then move the whole panel as a Label-PictureBox unit.  Then the Label and PictureBox would have the same coordinate reference (since they are in the same container).

To center the Label text (regardless of the text), do something like using the width of the text box to find where the midpoint would be. Then offset the Label by that midpoint (yet more coordinate math).